# ToolbarAndroid navIcon show small in 0.14

Tags: react-native

init new project, react-native:0.14.+

index.android.js content:

```
    <ToolbarAndroid
      navIcon={require('./ic_menu_white.png')}
      title='title'
      titleColor="green"
      style={styles.toolbar}
      actions={toolbarActions}
      onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected}
    />
    <Image source={require('./ic_menu_white.png')} />
```

but this navIcon image show small size, and Image is normal，why this ？

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same issue as yours. I don't have a solution but here's the workaround:

put "ic_menu_white.png" in the /android/app/src/main/res/drawable folder.

modify ToolbarAndroid as following:

```
<ToolbarAndroid
   navIcon={{ uri: 'ic_menu_white' }}
   title='title'
   titleColor="green"
   style={styles.toolbar}
   actions={toolbarActions}
   onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected}
 />
```

I found this workaround [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3943#issuecomment-155139757). Hope that would help.